# Return in pg-promise

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, pg-promise

I created a separate file with all my queries using `pg-promise` module for Node. While for most of them I just use `req, res` after a query, for one I want to return a value back. It does not work. It returns `undefined`.

```
passportLogin: (email)=> {
        db.one(`SELECT userid 
                FROM user`)
            .then( result => {
                return result;
            })
            .catch( error => {
                return error;
            });
    }
```

Comment: You define a function without a return value, so what do you expect? add a `return` before `db.one()` and you should get the promise.

Comment: Adding `return` before `db.one()` and getting rid of the other two `return`s gives back an empty object.

Comment: Your `then()` and `catch()` are pretty much useless here anyways, so get rid of them all together.

Comment: well the query is much more complex in reality, I need to catch if it returns more than one row... the object returned is still empty even if it should not be.

Comment: so why did you get rid of the two other `return`s then? If you return a value from a promise callback, it will return a new promise, which is resolved with that very value. I guess you will need the result in the code, which calls `passportLogin()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code has two problems at the same time:

- invalid promise use, when inside `.catch` you do `return result`, that's not how promise rejects are handled, you must either provide the error handling, or re-throw / re-reject the error.
- invalid use of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) library. You use method [one](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#one) that's supposed to  reject when anything other than 1 record is returned, [as per the method's documentation](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#one), and at the same time you are saying `I need to catch if it returns more than one row...` , which is a logical contradiction.

The result of it is as follows: your query executes successfully, and returns more than one record, which in turn makes method [one](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#one) reject, and then you take the rejection reason and turn it into a resolved one by doing `return result`. In all, your code is broken all over the place.

First, with [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) you are supposed to use the right method, according to the number of records you are expecting back, see [The Basics](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#basics).

And then handle `.then/.catch` according to your business logic. I can't be more specific here, because you did not provide further details on this.